# unable to find min and max outcome

Tags: java, math, arraylist

input: p=1,r=55,x=5

output:5
50

after iterating from 1 to 55,if the sum of digits =5 then
possible outcome will be 5,14,23,32,41,50
so the output is a smaller and greater outcome

I tried doing following code but I am getting index out of bond error.
I think it is because  `if(sum==x) list.add(i);` nothing is being added in this list.

```
import java.util.*;
public class wiley{
    static void find(int p,int r,int x){
        List<Integer> list= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int sum=0,temp,rem;
        for(int i=p;i<r;i++){
            temp=p;
            while(temp>0){
                rem=temp%10;
                sum+=rem;
                temp=p/10;
            }
            if(sum==x) list.add(i);
            sum=0;
        }
        int l=list.get(0);
        int m=list.get(list.size()-1);
        System.out.println(l);
        System.out.println(m);
    }




public static void main(String args[]){
int p=1;
int r=55;
int x=5;
find(p,r,x);
}
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question? If you get an exception, please add the stacktrace. Please adhere to general Java code formatting rules (class name not starting with an uppercase character in your case) to make it easier for us to spot bugs.

Comment: I'd like to add that you description of why the expected output is `5 50` is quite unclear. I personally have no idea why those 2 numbers are the expected output and what they are supposed to represent.

Comment: why did you put the `while` loop inside the for? it is independent of the loop index `i`, so you could execute it just once beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you get the error because nothing is added to the list.
This is because in your for loop, you iterate over the variable `i`, yet you declare `temp = p`. Change this line to `temp = i`.

Also, you have to change `temp=p/10` to `temp=temp/10` and you're good to go.

In addition, you should rewrite your function so that it does not throw an exception even if there is no element in the list. For example, you could check if the list size is greater than 0 and only then try to access its elements.